# Python printing format using """ """ format

Tags: python, printing

I am writing an email application to send mass emails. In the body of the email I want to insert the first name from a list of names. But I can't seem to figure out why this code isn't working. Any suggestions are most appreciated.

```
first_name = " "

body = """\
Dear {},
Here is new email.
Thanks.
Mike """.format(first_name)

def send_test_email(body):
  first_name = 'mike'
  print(body)

send_test_email(body)
```

Output:

Dear  ,

Here is new email.

Thanks.

Mike

Comment: You've asserted that the first name is literally ` `; you haven't grabbed it from your database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already assigned what `body` is. So even if you change value of parameter (`first_name`) in `format` later, it does not affect the original `body`.

```
first_name = " "

body = """\
Dear {},
Here is new email.
Thanks.
Mike """

def send_test_email(body):
  first_name = 'mike'
  print(body.format(first_name))

send_test_email(body)

# Dear mike,
# Here is new email.                                              
# Thanks.   
# Mike
```